# Python Ludwig: interpretation of final coding metric

Tags: deep-learning

I am learning über ludwig in Python. I ran the yaml definition file. I sat the epochs to 10. I have attached the screen shots of last 4 epochs.

Screen shot 1
[image]

Screen shot 2:

[image]

After running the program, it displays the best epochs

[image]

I am not sure how did it say epoch 7 hastiest validation model. If you look at other epoch, they have better training, vali, and test accuracy then how come it selected epoch 7. Could anyone shed some light on it?

Comment: Epoch 7 is the only one having lowest validation loss among all other epochs. It is the metric used to find the best model. If you use the training loss, the model will work best on training data but probably really bad on validation (overfitting). The test loss is probably calculated from data belonging to a complete different dataset than train and validation, so it does not make sense to save a model against it. To use accuracy to find the best model might not be a good idea: a decrease rate in loss does not always equal an increase in accuracy, but the model is still learning.

Comment: @dapetillo Thanks a lot for the insight. Its very useful. You explained it really well. However, I do not get the last sentence "but the model is still learning". Could you please explain it?

Comment: What I mean is that as long as the loss decreases, your model is learning features that optimally predict your outcome. But a 0.01% decrease in loss, does not equal a 0.01% increase in accuracy, because they are simply two different equations (loss has float numbers, accuracy is a sum of ones (right prediction) and zeros (wrong prediction) sum)